# extracting [ ] and " " JSONPath Zabbix

Tags: jsonpath, zabbix

I'm creating a monitoring in Zabbix where I want to perform a filter on a json.path removing `[]` and `""`.

**JSON**

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "date": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {},
        "value": [
          1666720385607,
          "3675"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Search**

```
$..[value].[1]
```

returns

```
[
  "3675"
]
```

I would like to get only the number without `[ " " ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$..[value].[1].first()`, see: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/items/preprocessing/jsonpath_functionality?hl=first